# filter: different behavior when argument is a string v/s variable

Tags: ansible

test.yml

```
---
- name: First playbook
  hosts: all
  vars:
    foo: '/var/tmp'
    t_path: '/var/tmp/foo/bar'

  tasks:
    - name: 'Passing string to relpath filter'
      debug:
        msg: '{{ t_path | relpath("/var/tmp") }}'

    - name: 'Passing variable to relpath filter'
      debug:
      msg: '{{ t_path | relpath("{{ foo }}") }}'
```

Output:

```
 < TASK [Passing string to relpath filter] >
 -----------------------------------------

ok: [host1] => {
"msg": "foo/bar"
}

< TASK [Passing variable to relpath filter] >
-------------------------------------------
ok: [host1] => {
 "msg": "../../../../var/tmp/foo/bar"
 }
```

Why is the variable interpreted differently in 2nd case?

What should be the correct way of passing a variable to ansible filters?

Comment: Already addressed in the answer below, but to stress the point -- when using a variable inside any jinja code such as `{{...}}` or `{%...%}`, don't use the {{}}'s again. No nested moustaches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing string `{{ foo }}` to the `relpath` filter and it returns the relative path from the directory named `{{ foo }}` inside the current directory (i.e., directory storing the temporary files being executed).

The correct syntax to refer to  the variable value inside a Jinja2 statement is:

```
- name: 'Passing variable to relpath filter'
  debug:
    msg: '{{ t_path | relpath(foo) }}'
```